# Using .c_str' with pointers (and also pointers to pointers)

Tags: c++, c-strings

so, I encountered a little problem and I am kinda stuck.
Basically I am trying to pass the value of a string** in C-type form to a char* string
The code is as follows:

```
static int BuildDBListSql( std::string **SqlBuf,
                          const char*   ColumnNames,
                          const char* TableNames,
                          const char*   CmdText,
                          sUINT Mode)   
{
   int rtnval = sSUCCESS;

   const char * testSql = ( Mode & 02 ) ? ColumnNames : CmdText;

   if ( SU_DbControl::DbCreateTradeTempTables(testSql) != sSUCCESS )
   {
      sLogMessage("Problem with temporary table results", sLOG_ERROR, 0);
      return( sERROR );
   }
   
   if ( Mode & 02 )     
   {
      *SqlBuf = new std::string[strlen(ColumnNames) + SQL_MAX_SELECT*40];
      *SqlBuf = &std::string(ColumnNames);
 
      if ( !( Mode & 010 ) )
      {
     // Attach State/Retrieval SQL.
        char* SqlBufcopy = (*SqlBuf)->c_str();
        sSQLInsertStateAndRetrieval( sDbConvertMode( Mode ), SqlBufcopy);
      }
   }
   // SQL fragments are being passed:
   else
   {
      size_t sqlBufLength = 0;
      if ( Mode & 010 )
      {
 
         sqlBufLength = strlen(ColumnNames) + strlen(TableNames) + strlen(CmdText) + SQL_MAX_SELECT;
         *SqlBuf = new std::string[ sqlBufLength ];
     //sprintf( *SqlBuf, "SELECT %s FROM %s %s ",
         *SqlBuf = fmt::format("SELECT {} FROM {} {} ", ColumnNames, TableNames, CmdText);  // ColumnNames, TableNames, CmdText );
        
      }
      else
      {
         std::string *sqlPtr = new char[strlen(CmdText) + 2*SQL_MAX_SELECT];
     strcpy( sqlPtr, CmdText );
 
     sSQLSpecializeWhereClause( TableNames, sqlPtr );

         sqlBufLength = strlen(ColumnNames) + strlen(TableNames) + SQL_MAX_SELECT;
         sqlBufLength += strchr(TableNames, ',') ? strlen(CmdText) : strlen(sqlPtr);
         *SqlBuf = new char[ sqlBufLength ];
     sprintf( *SqlBuf, "SELECT %s From %s %s",
                 ColumnNames,
                 TableNames,
                 strchr( TableNames, ',' ) ? CmdText : sqlPtr );
     delete [] sqlPtr;
     // Attach State/Retrieval SQL
     rtnval = sSQLInsertStateAndRetrieval( sDbConvertMode( Mode ),
                          *SqlBuf );
      }
   }
   if (Mode & 0100)
   {
      char * tempBuf = sEntitySQLToDbSQL(*SqlBuf);
      if( tempBuf )
      {
         delete [] *SqlBuf;
         *SqlBuf = new char[ strlen(tempBuf) + 1];
         strcpy(*SqlBuf, tempBuf);
      }
      else
      {
         sLogMessage("Error in sEntitySQLToDbSQL", sLOG_ERROR, 0);
         return( sERROR );
      }
   }

   return rtnval;
}
```

i get this error when running the solution: related to this line of code char* SqlBufcopy = (*SqlBuf)->c_str();

```
left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union, type is std::string**
```

I kinda understand that the error is there due to me trying to get a c-type string out of a pointer, but I dont know the correct syntax to do what i want to do.

I tried with

```
 char *SqlBufcopy = *SqlBuf.c_str()
```

also with

```
 char *SqlBufcopy = *SqlBuf->c_str()
```

and it didnt work, help pls

Comment: This code is all kinds of wrong. Dereferencing uninitialized pointer `SqlBuf`, invoking `strlen` on uninitialized pointer `ColumnNames`, blatant memory leak by blasting over the questionable storage to `*SqlBuf` on successive lines, etc.

Comment: Did you get identical error messages? If not, please also show the errors for your alternative attempts.

Comment: Your code really makes no sense at all, TBH. How to fix it... that depends on what `SqlBufcopy` is supposed to be and what it is supposed to contain. Please work on this, and try to create a [mcve]` or at least something with more complete code, with variables actually initialized, and showing how `SqlBufcopy` is actually used.

Comment: @WhozCraig i dont really think it is, all the code that i posted above is part of a bigger code. I only posted what i thought you needed to see in order to help me. Also, all variables are initialised as they are function parameters

Comment: Also, compile with warnings enabled. Google how to enable warnings for your compiler and build system.

Comment: @hyde, so first ill describe whats going on and after that ill post more code:
basically i need this char* sqlbufcopy to copy the string inside string** sqlbuf

Comment: @hyde updated code, btw, the sollution that was posted bellow worked, idk who erased it but it was really helpful

Comment: Undeleted the answer. I'll check it later against the code you posted.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error you ask about, change `char *SqlBufcopy = *SqlBuf.c_str();` to

```
char *SqlBufcopy = (*SqlBuf)->c_str();
```

Reason: `SqlBuf` is pointer to pointer (which makes no sense at all), so to get to the actual object, you need to dereference it twice.

Comment: It's a double-star type and should be `(**SQlBuf).c_str()`, no?

Comment: @j6t Right... Fixed.